# Joining multiple different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, aggregation

Example to join 4 or more tables

```
t1 - f1,f2,f3
t2 - f1,f4,f5
t3 - f4,f6,f7,f8
t4 - f8,f9
```

t1,t2,t3,t4 are 4 tables and f... are corresponding fields. Please suggest a join query which is optimized for computation and memory. Eg; I want to know how many f2 X f4 X f7 X f8.

Does the order of joining tables and size of tables have any impact on sql syntax?

I searched through multiple forums and somewhere inner join is being used and UNION and somewhere sub queries.

Please explain with syntax of MySQL.

Comment: RTFineM: [Optimizing SELECT Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-optimization.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just write all the joins one after the other.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.f1 = t2.f1
JOIN t3 ON t2.f4 = t3.f4
JOIN t4 ON t3.f8 = t4.f8
```

The order of the joins shouldn't matter. Make sure you have indexes on all the columns being used in the `ON` conditions.

Comment: Just to add on to @Barmar's answer, take a look at the types of join options  available so that you have an idea of what type of join you may want to use, they have different behavior depending on what you're looking for.